# C# - Selecting SQL Table contents into textbox

Tags: c#, sql, select

Trying to get table contents into textBoxes seperately by the prefered ID number when button_click event occours. I've found some videos about the situation but dataGrids were used in those. I'm a complete newbie in C# btw, and i'm not even sure what i'm doing.

Question is, i cant figure how to write a read-only object that is stated below in code into a textBox. I'm %90 sure that it's truly a simple thing, and i'm missing it.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand rcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, Column1, Column2 FROM [TEST].[dbo].[Table_1] where ID=@ID", connection);
    rcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", textBox3.Text);
    connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = rcmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //textBox4.Text = reader["Column1"];
        //textBox5.Text = reader["Column2"];
        //These wont work, says reader["Column1"] and reader["Column2"] are read-only. What to do?
    }
    connection.Close();
```

Lines with error are intentionally commented. No mistake there. I was trying to figure something else while keeping those in my sight.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should do the opposite... textBox4.Text = reader["Column1"], since you're setting the value of the text box to the value from the reader.

Comment: @Alex Yeah, you'd normaly do that eheh. But still wont work. :L
Says cannot implicitly change object to string. Oh wait. I think i'm getting some insights.

Comment: @Alex what happens when you do it? Any errors?

Comment: Just edited the comment.

Comment: `textBox4.Text = reader["Column1"].ToString()` ?

Comment: So i just had to convert reader["Column1"] "object" to string with .ToString() eh? This works. :) Thanks!

Comment: How you reported Visual Studio saying `reader["Column1"] and reader["Column2"] are read-only` is anyone's guess

Comment: @JeremyThompson i'm way behind you all eh? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
reader["Column1"].ToString();
```

You're missing `ToString()`

Comment: Thank you kindly :)

Comment: Dude, do yourself a favor and pick up a beginners C# book

Comment: Thanks again for your concern.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommand rcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, Column1, Column2 FROM [TEST].[dbo].[Table_1] where ID=@ID", connection);

            rcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", textBox3.Text);
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = rcmd.ExecuteReader();


            while (reader.Read())
            {

                textBox4.Text = reader["Column1"].ToString();
                textBox5.Text = reader["Column2"].ToString();

            }
            connection.Close();
       }
```